# Head First Design Patterns - Decorator Pattern Description/Cost

Tags: design-patterns, decorator

I am quite new to OO Design Patterns and relatively new to Java.

My question is about the Decorator example in Head First Designer Patterns Starbuzz example.

I'm having trouble understanding how the outer wrapper call the inner wrappers and specifically how the descriptions in these examples get concatenated.

For example:

Here is the Mocha class (decoration):

```
public class Mocha extends CondimentsDecorator {

Beverage beverage;

public Mocha(Beverage beverage) {

    this.beverage = beverage;
}

public String getDescription()
{
    return beverage.getDescription() + " , Mocha";
}

public double cost()
{
    return .20 +  beverage.cost();
}

}
```

Here is the Beverage class (base):

```
public abstract class Beverage {

String description = "Unknown Beverage";

public String getDescription()
{

    return description;
}

public abstract double cost();

}
```

Dark Roast Class:

```
public class DarkRoast extends Beverage {

public DarkRoast() {
    description = "Dark Roast";
}

@Override
public double cost() {

    return .99;
}

}
```

So, if I run this:

```
 Beverage beverage2 = new DarkRoast();
 beverage2 = new Mocha(beverage2);
 beverage2 = new Mocha(beverage2);

 System.out.println(beverage2.getDescription() + " $" + beverage2.cost());
```

The output is:

```
Dark Roast , Mocha , Mocha $1.39
```

I don't understand how the descriptions are built and costs added together? How is the state of the description and cost kept? Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 5):

It will help if you don't reuse names.

### Example of meaningful names

Suppose you had written the code as:

```java
Beverage roast = new DarkRoast();
mocha = new Mocha(roast);
doubleMocha = new Mocha(mocha);
System.out.println(doubleMocha.getDescription() + " $" + doubleMocha.cost());
```

The variable `mocha` is a Mocha, and `mocha.beverage == roast`, a DarkRoast.

The variable `doubleMocha` is a Mocha, and `doubleMocha.beverage == mocha`, a Mocha.

Note that `doubleMocha.beverage.beverage == roast`. And the cost can be delegated down the chain, too:

```
dobleMocha.cost() == .20 + doubleMocha.beverage.cost() 
                  == .20 + mocha.cost() 
                  == .20 + .20 + mocha.beverage.cost()
                  == .20 + .20 + roast.cost()
                  == .20 + .20 + 1.99 = 2.39
```

You can figure out `doubleMocha.description()` the same way.

#### Other issues

As you progress, you'll learn a few more things.

1. Decorators are used heavily in Java IO.  One wraps InputReaders in BufferedInputReaders, and then possibly in more exotic classes.
2. Never use `float`s or `double`s for currency values.  Have you ever seen the results of naive code that applies say a 4.5% tax on your $2.99 item and reports it as $3.12455?  It's easy to round things incorrectly too.

#### Read more

If you can find a used copy of following book, buy it:

- [A Little Java, A Few Patterns](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/470776.A_Little_Java_a_Few_Patterns) by Felleisen, Friedman, and Johnson

It has a great description of this type of code.

#### Garbage collector kept references

By the way, the original code that uses only one variable name works because first the variable is set to a `DarkRoast` object.  Then the routine creates a `Mocha` object that uses the `DarkRoast` object, and once the instance variable is set to the `Mocha` object, the original `DarkRoast` is still strongly reachable. The garbage collector does not dispose of it.

Comment: Thank you Eric for the excellent explanation and for including the bit on garbage collection and "strongly usable".

This helped alot!

Comment: Your answer read like a good long advice from a potpourri of experience. I tried to beautify it even more, see [my edit's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15725498/3). Hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 1):

The description is built with

```
public String getDescription() 
{
    return beverage.getDescription() + " , Mocha";
}
```

Notice that the description of the `Mocha` calls the description of the `Beverage` class.

The cost is calculated by

```
public double cost()
{
    return .20 +  beverage.cost();
}
```

So the cost of the `Mocha` class calls the cost of the `Beverage` class as part of its calculation.

Comment: Thank you Jeff...I just didn't get that the values were kept in memory after reassignment of the variable.

Comment: Well, they're not kept in memory.  The functions get called and recalculated each time.